# Symfony2: How to get request parameter

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a route:

```
professor_identity_edit:
path:     /professor/{id}/identity
defaults: { _controller: FrontBundle:ProfessorIdentity:edit }
```

How can I get the parameter `{id}` in `twig.html` file ?

I already tried `app.request.query.get('id')` but with no success.

Comment: You should be passing it from your controller to twig, not getting it from the request from inside twig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a good thing but you can still do. Normally you would pass the info to Twig from the controller like @Maerlyn pointed out.

Get route parameters in Twig.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') }}
```

AND

Gets whole bundle name in Twig.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get("_controller") }}
```

Get route name in Twig.

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')['id'] }}
```

Comment: You can use the "deep" parameter and not need to do chaining like `app.request.attributes.get('_route_params[id]', null, true)`.